# Task.ContinueWith query

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I`m new to TPL and need some help in understanding .continueWith. Can you pls tell me what is wrong in first task-continuation and how is second one correct?

```
List<int> input = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

 //Gives cast error at the second continuation: cannot implicitly convert 
 //Task to Task<List<int>>
    Task<List<int>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>(
        (state) => { return (List<int>)state; }, input)

        .ContinueWith<List<int>>(
        (prevTask => { return (List<int>)prevTask.Result; }))

        .ContinueWith(
        (prevTask => { Console.WriteLine("All completed"); }));

    //Works fine
    Task<List<int>> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>(
        (state) => { return (List<int>)state; }, input);

    task1.ContinueWith<List<int>>(
        (prevTask => { return (List<int>)prevTask.Result; }))

        .ContinueWith(
        (prevTask => { Console.WriteLine("All completed"); }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first chain of method calls you made ends with `ContinueWith()` which returns a `Task` object which can't be assigned to a `Task<List<int>>`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>(...) // returns Task<List<int>>
    .ContinueWith<List<int>>(...) // returns Task<List<int>>
    .ContinueWith(...); // returns Task
```

But in the second one, the result of the last `ContinueWith` is not assigned to anything, so works fine.

For the first one to work, either define `task` as `Task`:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>(
    (state) => { return (List<int>)state; }, input)

    .ContinueWith<List<int>>(
    (prevTask => { return (List<int>)prevTask.Result; }))

    .ContinueWith(
    (prevTask => { Console.WriteLine("All completed"); }));
```

Or make the last call a generic one:

```
Task<List<int>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>(
    (state) => { return (List<int>)state; }, input)

    .ContinueWith<List<int>>(
    (prevTask => { return (List<int>)prevTask.Result; }))

    .ContinueWith<List<int>>(
    (prevTask => { Console.WriteLine("All completed"); }));
```